# Webform [submission:values]: field name and value inverted

Tags: webforms

Recently,  [submission:values] inverts my field name and the value like this:

TestName Name

0600000000 Phone number

Do you know how to display correctly my submission with [submission:values] ?

To have this instead:

Name TestName

Phone number 0600000000

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using an RTL or LTR language?

Comment: Hello, we are using LTR

Comment: If you can replicate this issue using https://simplytest.me, please post an example webform in the Webform module's issue queue.